# Postgresql Trigger to insert rows

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert-into

I'm stuck for days with triggers on Postgresql (and Mysql as well). I just want to insert newly filled rows to another table. The original data comes from an external form (OpenDataKit) and goes to "intermediate" tables. I can't understand why the form cannot send the data anymore once the trigger is created... Note that all actions work without the trigger, when I do the insertions by hand. I would greatly appreciate some help to understand what I am doing wrong.
 I am now testing with Postgresql 9.5, but I got similar issue with MySQL 5.1.

```
-- CREATE procedure: 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_natobs() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO lieu (id_lieu, wgs_lat, wgs_lon, date_obs, geom)    
    SELECT  id_loc,"GPS_TEL_LAT", "GPS_TEL_LNG", "DATE_OBS", ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT("GPS_TEL_LNG","GPS_TEL_LAT"), 4326)
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC", "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"
    WHERE "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"."_URI" = "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI"
    AND "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC".id_loc IN (SELECT max(id_loc) FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC");

INSERT INTO i_lieu_observateurs (id_lieu, id_auteur)
    SELECT id_loc, CAST("AUTEUR" AS integer) 
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE", "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"
    WHERE "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI" = "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"."_URI"
     AND id_loc IN (SELECT max(id_loc) FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC")
    UNION 
    SELECT id_loc, CAST("OBSERVATEURS" AS integer) 
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC", "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR"
    WHERE "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI" = "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR"."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI"
    AND id_loc IN (SELECT max(id_loc) FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC")
    ;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- CREATE the trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_natobs AFTER INSERT
ON "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_natobs();
```

So, when the ODK form inserts new rows in FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC (for which I have created a serial ID to facilitate the SQL queries), I try to insert this row (combined with information from other intermediate tables) into table "lieu" for the first action of the trigger, and into table i_lieu_observation (composed by a double primary key) for the second action. I tested also with a trigger composed by the first action only, but it does not work either. The Android app that sends the form crashes until I remove the trigger.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using `MAX(id_loc) FROM FORMULAIRE_...` you should use `new.xxx` to check for the row that fired the trigger.

Comment: It would help if you added the definitions for all the referred tables to the question. To me it looks like there is a 1:N relation between the two tables lieu and i_lieu_observateurs. And it would certainly help if you used JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the special NEW variable in the trigger to access the newly inserted data.  So you need something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_natobs() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO lieu (id_lieu, wgs_lat, wgs_lon, date_obs, geom)    
    SELECT  new.id_loc,"GPS_TEL_LAT", "GPS_TEL_LNG", "DATE_OBS", ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT("GPS_TEL_LNG","GPS_TEL_LAT"), 4326)
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"
    WHERE "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"."_URI" = new."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI";

INSERT INTO i_lieu_observateurs (id_lieu, id_auteur)
    SELECT new.id_loc, CAST("AUTEUR" AS integer) 
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"
WHERE new."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI" = "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE"."_URI"
    UNION 
    SELECT new.id_loc, CAST("OBSERVATEURS" AS integer) 
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR"
    WHERE new."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI" = "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR"."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI";
RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- CREATE the trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_natobs AFTER INSERT
ON "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_natobs();
```

Because I don't know which fields come from which tables, I cannot make the above totally correct.  In the same way as I have written new.id_loc, you will need to put new.field_name for all fields coming from the formulaire_natobs_repeat_loc table.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. But see my comment to @Paarth

Comment: I take it that FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE and FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR do have values that equate to the new."TOP_LEVEL_AURI"?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it still does not work, the app crashes. However, when I mix your script with the one of Paarth, that is adding "IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN .... END IF", the form does send the data, but it's like the trigger does not trigger anything. Do you have some idea? Yes, the link between ODK's tables is _CORE._URI = _REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR._TOP_LEVEL_AURI = _REPEAT_LOC._TOP_LEVEL_AURI, with one row in _CORE that could be connected to multiple rows in LOC and OBSERVATEUR tables.

Comment: IF (TG_OP etc should not be necessary if the function is only called after insert.  Have you tried adding a row manually in pgadmin?  Could you post any error message?  Also I presume you have the db insert in a try .. catch .  What Exception gets thrown?

Comment: Actually, that is a good point. When I insert row manually, the trigger works! I start by filling _CORE and _OBSERVATEUR before _LOC, so that the trigger can return something. I am thus wondering whether it would be possible that ODK's form sends the rows sequentially, starting for instance with the _LOC table, so that the trigger works but returns NULL as _CORE and _OBSERVATEUR are still empty at that time?

Comment: That was my guess too!  Unfortunately I do not use ODK, so cannot help you further.  I suggest you open a new question about how to ensure ODK updates tables sequentially and mark the trigger one as answered (because the trigger clearly works!).  You will attract hopefully a different set of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_natobs() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

BEGIN

IF(TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

INSERT INTO lieu (id_lieu, wgs_lat, wgs_lon, date_obs, geom)    
    SELECT  id_loc,"GPS_TEL_LAT", "GPS_TEL_LNG", "DATE_OBS", ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT("GPS_TEL_LNG","GPS_TEL_LAT"), 4326)
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC" loc, "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE" core
    WHERE core."_URI" = loc."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI"
    AND loc.id_loc =new.id_loc;

INSERT INTO i_lieu_observateurs (id_lieu, id_auteur)
    SELECT id_loc as id, 
    CAST("AUTEUR" AS integer)  as auteur
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_CORE" core, "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC" loc
    WHERE loc."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI" = core."_URI"
     AND loc.id_loc =new.id_loc;
    UNION 
    SELECT id_loc as id, 
    CAST("OBSERVATEURS" AS integer) as auteur
    FROM "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC" loc, "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_OBSERVATEUR" obs
    WHERE loc."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI" = obs."_TOP_LEVEL_AURI"
    AND loc.id_loc =new.id_loc;
    END IF;

   Return new;  
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

-- CREATE the trigger:
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_natobs AFTER INSERT
ON "FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_natobs();
```

Hope it work for you.

Comment: Thanks! It is going better in the sense that the form is now filling the ODK's "FORMULAIRE_xx" tables, but the trigger does not return anything. Tables "lieu" and "i_lieu_observateurs" are still empty... Do you have any additional tips please?

Comment: Check Trigger is enabled or not. If trigger is enabled and there is any error in trigger, `"FORMULAIRE_NATOBS_REPEAT_LOC"` table would also not filled. check trigger.

Comment: If trigger is ok  then try insert query with some dummy data for Tables "lieu" and "i_lieu_observateurs". Is insert is working or not for given tables.